# Accessing a custom property using Javascript in an ASP.NET project

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working on a project that has a custom HTMLEditor control (named MyHTMLEditor) derived from System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl.

Inside MyHTMLEditor control, is aggregated an instance of MyEditor control deriving from AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor control.

Below is the code.

```
    public class MyHTMLEditor : CompositeControl
         {
               private MyEditor _myEditor = new MyEditor();

               public MyEditor EditorControl
                {
                      get { return this._myEditor; }

                }
         }


     public class MyEditor : Editor //AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor control
         {

         }
```

This is my Javascript function which accesses the property EditorControl:

```
    var editorControl = document.getElementById('<%= rtxtFindings.ClientID %>'); 
    var editorPanel = editorControl.EditorControl; // Failing..
```

The second line of the above code is failing - it shows editorControl.EditorControl as undefined.

Since I'm new to Javascript, I'm not very sure of the reason behind it.

My guess is: since all the controls are rendered as HTML controls, the custom properties added are ignored or are not considered. But if this were to be true, I wonder what if one wishes to add custom methods/properties to a control wanting them to be accessed via Javascript - how would that be possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself :)

Inclusion of the custom property (see below) does the trick.

```
var editorControl = document.getElementById('<%= rtxtFindings.EditorControl.ClientID %>');
```